# Qt C++ class does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, class, global-variables

I´m trying to put a ComboBox ater a query and put the results into a QtableView.

My query works and the table view shows the results, my combobox receive the first column elements but...

When I try to make a new query on on_comboBox_pedido_currentIndexChanged, my query results is always empty.

I tried to put my "Login teste" declaration class as public and appears "'Login' does not name a type"

This is my pedidos.h . I tried do create a public teste here!!!

```
#ifndef PEDIDOS_H
#define PEDIDOS_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class Pedidos;
}

class Pedidos : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Login teste;  // not working - "does not name a type" error

    explicit Pedidos(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Pedidos();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_load_pedidos_clicked();

    void on_comboBox_pedido_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);

private:
    Ui::Pedidos *ui;
};

#endif // PEDIDOS_H
```

And this is my pedidos.cpp

```
#include "login.h"
#include "pedidos.h"
#include "ui_pedidos.h"

Pedidos::Pedidos(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Pedidos)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Login conn;

    if(!conn.connOpen())
       ui->label_pedidos_conn->setText("Falha na conexão ao Database");
    else{
       ui->label_pedidos_conn->setText("Database Ok");
       conn.connClose();
     }

}

Pedidos::~Pedidos()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Pedidos::on_pushButton_load_pedidos_clicked()
{
    Login conn;
    QSqlQueryModel *modal=new QSqlQueryModel();

    QSqlQuery *qry=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

    qry->prepare("SELECT pedido.id_pedido, usuarios.nome_user, endereco.bairro, \
                         pedido.id_user, pedido.data   FROM pedido \
                  INNER JOIN usuarios ON pedido.id_user=usuarios.id_user \
                  INNER JOIN endereco ON pedido.id_endereco=endereco.id_endereco \
                  WHERE pedido.status=0");

            qry->exec();

    qDebug() << qry->lastError().text();

    modal->setQuery(*qry);

    modal->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Pedido");
    modal->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Usuário");
    modal->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Bairro");

    ui->tableView_pedidos->setModel(modal);

    ui->comboBox_pedido->setModel(modal);  // My ComboBox here!

    ui->tableView_pedidos->resizeRowsToContents();
    ui->tableView_pedidos->resizeColumnsToContents();

   ui->tableView_pedidos->setColumnHidden(3, true);
   ui->tableView_pedidos->setColumnHidden(4, true);

    while(qry->next()){

        QString usuario = qry->value(0).toString();
        qDebug() << "id:" << usuario;
    }

    //qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());

}

void Pedidos::on_comboBox_pedido_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QString id_pedido=ui->comboBox_pedido->currentText();
    qDebug() << id_pedido;



       QSqlQueryModel *modal2=new QSqlQueryModel();

//works until here...if uncomment any line from here nok

        Login meudb;  // this line uncommented, query on pushbutton is not working ( blank )
        //QSqlQuery *qry=new QSqlQuery(meudb.mydb);
        //meudb.connClose();


}
```

If I comment the line "Login meudb", the query results is ok.

So I tried to create a global "Login teste" to replace my local "Login conn".

I read many articles here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing a `#include "login.h"` in your pedidos.h file.

Comment: This was my first option...not working. But in my pedidos.cpp there is a login.h before pedidos.h.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your file pedidos.h :

```
#ifndef PEDIDOS_H
#define PEDIDOS_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QtWidgets>

class Login;
...
```

Comment: I implemented your hint. The compiler shows: "field 'teste' has incomplete type 'Login' ".

Comment: Let me explain better my problem. I´m trying to use a "Login" global class to fix my problem in combobox inside pedidos.cpp. The "Login" class is recognized in all methods inside pedidos.pcc, but when I define a "Login" inside a combobox method, my last query is completely blank. I don´t understand why.